# generic sql syntax error 1064

Tags: php, mysql

```
$products = "CREATE TABLE products (
PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
productID VARCHAR(255),
articlenr VARCHAR(255),
name VARCHAR(255),
desc VARCHAR(255),
price VARCHAR(255),
image VARCHAR(255),
flag VARCHAR(255),
date VARCHAR(255)
)";
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc VARCHAR(255), price VARCHAR(255), image VARCHAR(255), flag VARCHAR(255), da' at line 2

not exactly a question that others could use, but where else should I ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `desc` with backticks

```
CREATE TABLE products 
(
  PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  productID VARCHAR(255),
  articlenr VARCHAR(255),
  name VARCHAR(255),
  `desc` VARCHAR(255),
  price VARCHAR(255),
  image VARCHAR(255),
  flag VARCHAR(255),
  date VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Or as @Rocket suggests don't use such reserved words as table or column names at all.

Comment: Or better yet, don't use `desc` as a field name.